# Filter state doesn't work correctly in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management

My Parent component retrieves the **checked inputs value** from its child component. 
So I have a function *(handleChecked)* that takes two parameters : one *'id'* and one checked status *'isChecked'* :

```
const handleChecked = useCallback(({ id, isChecked }) => {

    const newCheckedValues = checkedValues.filter(current => current !== id);

    setCheckedValues(newCheckedValues);

    if (isChecked) {
        newCheckedValues.push(id);
        setCheckedValues(newCheckedValues);
    }
}, [checkedValues]);
```

> What my function is supposed to do :

1 - Get id and checked status from the clicked input,
 2 - Check the state for duplicate id's,
 3 - If present, remove it,
 4 - Save the state,
 5 - If checked, store the id in a temporary array,
 6 - Save the new state.

> What it does :

- Well, all the task above except adding the value to the new state.

When I **click a new input**, the parent **"checkedValues" state is empty** and starts over from nothing.
Meaning that the temporary array created as the result of the filtered state, is also empty.
Right now, this function just adds an id in the state, then replace it by the new clicked input.

And I need to gather **all the checked values** and **store them in the state** before sending that to an api later. I manage to present my "expectations" in this sandbox :

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-filter-state-array-toggle-input-checked-gz504

It works, the only difference is it's in the same component and uses html **form event** and not **props legacy**.

Comment: You're calling `setCheckedValues(newCheckedValues);` twice, once passing the old array without `id`, then again with `id` inside. state updates are async though; you should do `if ... push` first, then call `setCheckedValues(newCheckedValues);` once, at the end.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your answer. I did think of that but it does not change the problem unfortunately. At first I thought the _filter function_ was the issue but it does its job : if I click the same input, `isChecked` turns false and the value is removed from the state. So I still have my "addition" problem.

Comment: I'm looking at the sandbox and it seems to work fine? edit: didn't read the last sentence, give me a sec

Comment: Alright, here's my solution: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-filter-state-array-toggle-input-checked-cyhrr

Comment: So the solution would be to pass the function into the child ? I wasn't sure you can useState setter as prop...Unless parent and child have to be in the same file/component ? I'm gonna work on that asap and let you know.

Comment: They don't have to be in the same file, no. You can pass whatever as prop, and in React, sending data from a child to a parent works just like that: pass the mutator function to the child as prop, then call it from the child.

Comment: After a few tries, putting the map() function in the children to deal with the parent state update did work. @ChrisG Thank you so much for your time, comments and sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I deconstructed my component in 3 :

1. A **Parent** component with the `checkedValues` state which calls a "ListItem" child, passing **datas and states** as **props** ;
2. A **ListItem** component which contains the `handleCheck` function and map the datas to display, passing the infos and the function to **each mapped child**.
3. An **Item** component which displays an input with its datas and the `handleCheck` function + deals with its own `isChecked` state to modify CSS dynamically according to its status.

This answer is of course customized to my own purposes and needs. It's not the most general but it answers my question and can maybe help someone. Thanks again @ChrisG for your help